# Matching and replacing multiple $variables in line

Tags: regex, perl

I'm attempting to write a very basic shell to python converter, and I'm having some trouble replacing variables. Example, I want:

```
echo $var1 $var2 $var3
echo $var1 $var2 $var3 $var4
```

to become:

```
print var1, var2, var3
print var1, var2, var3, var4
```

currently, it becomes:

```
print var1, var2 var3
print var1, var2 var3, var4
```

My regex is:

```
$string =~ s/(\$[a-z]+[a-z0-9]*)(\s+\S+)/$1,$2/gi;
```

for some reason, it doesn't apply the regex again to the second part of the matched string, even though the global modifier is set.

Very thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Keeping close to your regex, try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = '$var1 $var2 $var3 $var4$var5';

$string =~ s/\$([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\s*/$1, /gi;
$string =~ s/,\s*$//; #removing trailing comma
print $string . "\n";
```

**Output:**

```
var1, var2, var3, $var4
```

Or I would simply do this, which may or may not work with some other things you may have.

```
s/\$(\w+)\s*/$1, /g
```

Comment: Good one. Although this would fail for this string: `echo $var1 $var2 $var3 $var4$var6`. Also you don't need `A-Z` as you already have used the insensitive flag at the end.

Comment: @kash You are right. I fixed it now. However it is going to add a trailing `,` and so is your below solution. Wonder how I can avoid adding trailing comma.

Comment: Good catch. Is there an online tester where we can test the perl code (not just the regex but the replaces too)? I presume we can capture the last variable in a different group and try `$1, $2`. Not sure if that would work.

Comment: @Kash It was right before us in the OP... lol I feel really stupid.

Comment: Um wouldn't that match only var1 and var3? I don't think `\S+` is right in this case?

Comment: You are right. neither `\S+` or `\S` would work. I got a little excited there.. :D Back to extra regex for removing trailing comma

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to modify your regex to:

```
$string =~ s/\$([a-z][a-z0-9]*)(?:\s*|$)/$1, /gi; 
$string =~ s/,\s*$//; #courtesy Hameed
```

The non capturing group would ensure that the variable ends either with a space, or no space at all or would be at the end of the line.

This would also match echoes like `$var1 $var2 $var3 $var4$var6` and output `var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6`

Answer (score 0):

Once it has matched the the (\s+\S+) the regex engine has moved passed the 2nd variable.
A lookahead assertion will allow it to check what is ahead without consuming the string

```
 $string =~ s{
   \$ 
   ( [a-z]+[a-z0-9]* )  # capture varname
   (?=\s+\S+)           # lookahead
 } {$1,}gix ;
```

Note that I am neither matching nor capturing the \s+S+ so no need to include it as $2 in the replacement string. And the /x allows me to space the regex out and add add comments.

Note - other answers may give a closer match to what you are tring to do. I am just explaining your specific query about not matching the 2nd variable.

Answer (score 0):

Make your substitution conditional on whether the variable occurs at the end of the line with

```
$string =~ s{\$([a-z]+[a-z0-9]*)(\s*$)?}{ defined $2 ? $1 : "$1," }ge;
```

The subpattern that corresponds to `$2` is `(\s*$)?`. The `?` makes the match optional, so `$2` will be defined only when that pattern matches successfully, that is, for the last variable on the line—even in the presence of invisible trailing whitespace. For an “interior” variable, append a comma to the end. Otherwise, the variable name only will do.

For example

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (defined(my $string = <DATA>)) {
  $string =~ s{\$([a-z]+[a-z0-9]*)(\s*$)?}{ defined $2 ? $1 : "$1," }ge;
  $string =~ s/\becho\b/print/g;  # for demo only
  print $string, "\n";
}

__DATA__
echo $var1 $var2 $var3
echo $var1 $var2 $var3 $var4
```

Output:

```
print var1, var2, var3
print var1, var2, var3, var4
```